# Void pointer type conversion

Tags: c, pointers

I want to print addresses of void pointer

```
u32 j;
for (j = 0; j < sizeof(struct queue_header); j += 4) 
{
    printf("0x%x ",(u32 *)((u32 *)q->q_hdr + j)); //q_hdr  is a void pointer        
}
```

but that type conversion is giving error:

> warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]

can you please tell me how can I print the address.

Comment: `j += 4` is wrong: if you cast to `u32 *`, you are already counting in terms of `u32`s, so `j++` would be right.

Comment: Side note: one `(u32*)` casting is sufficient in this case.

Comment: Side note #2: Use `%x` for `int` (or smaller) variables, `%lx` for `long int` variables, `%llx` for `long long int` variables, and `%p` for `Type*` (pointer) variables.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's what `%p` is for: printing pointers.

```
printf("%p ", (void *)((u32 *)q->q_hdr + j));
```

should do what you want.

Comment: One question : u32 = uint32_t ?

Comment: @Gopi From the context I conclude that the OP has somewhere a `typedef uint32_t u32`.

Comment: @user694733: Mandatory by the standard? I would be very interested in seeing a platform on which this casting actually makes a difference.

Comment: @barakmanos Yes. Since platform is not mentioned, we can only rely on rules from C standard.

Comment: @user694733 it's not mandatory, it's completely unnecessary and very bad programming style

Comment: @TomTanner It is mandatory. N1570 7.21.6.1.8 on specifier `p` says "The argument shall be a pointer to **void**". Pointer to any other data type is not implicitly converted to `void*` when using it as parameter to variable argument functions.

Comment: And there can be platforms where `void *` and `char *` have a format different from other pointer types.

Answer (score 0):

Is your code running on a 64-bit platform (Intel Core 2 Duo, i7)?

Perhaps "%lx" would work for the printf.

You'll need to cast the argument to printf to a 64-bit integer as well.

Comment: It's `%llx`, and if you want to maintain platform-compatibility, then you should use `%p`.